# Repeat same test until a condition is met and finish execution in Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, automated-tests

I have a .xlsx file that contains in each row the parameters needed to execute different automated tests on a website. 
The way I have it set up is something like this:

```
public class X_Test {
int start = Integer.valueOf(config.Get("StartRow"));
int end = Integer.valueOf(config.Get("EndRow"));//last row on the excel

@Test
@Repeat(end) //not working because ¨end¨ is not known at compilation time. 
public void main() throws Throwable 
{ 
   for(int i = start ; i < end ; i++)
    {
     // I need to change this loop for a Repeat(#) test.
     //selenium and report code here
    }
}
```

The issue is that this code executes the whole .xlsx file as one test when I need it to take each row as an individual test.

The problems I need to fix are:

- I need the same method @test main() to be executed multiple times to generate one junit test per row in the .xlsx file.
- The @Repeat(#) works if I fix the number of rows in the excel file to the same # in repeat tag. The problem is that each excel file that I test has a different number of rows so I need it to repeat only until the last row on the .xlsx file. Maybe I can implement a condition test? How can I do this.

Comment: It sounds like a parameterized test might be what you are after - https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow up on my comment, I believe [parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests) are what you are looking for. In short, a parameterized test can run the same tests/assertions against a set of test data.

> The issue is that this code executes the whole .xlsx file as one test
>   when I need it to take each row as an individual test.

If this is the case, you could do a parameterized test where your parameters are populated by reading and parsing your .xlsx. Here's a sample of what I mean:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class SampleTest {

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() throws Exception{

        //TODO: Instead of hard coding this data, read and parse your .xlsx however you see fit, and return a collection of all relevant values. These will later be passed in when constructing your test class, and then can be used in your test method
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                { 1,1,2 }, { 2,2,4 }, { 3,3,6 }, { 4,4,8 }, { 5,5,10 }
        });
    }


    private int intOne;
    private int intTwo;
    private int expected;

    public SampleTest(final int intOne, final int intTwo, final int expected) {
        this.intOne = intOne;
        this.intTwo = intTwo;
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Verifying that " + this.intOne + " and " + this.intTwo + " equals " + this.expected);
        Assert.assertEquals(this.intOne + this.intTwo, this.expected);
    }
}
```

Running this produces a set of 5 successful tests, and the output:

```
Verifying that 1 and 1 equals 2
Verifying that 2 and 2 equals 4
Verifying that 3 and 3 equals 6
Verifying that 4 and 4 equals 8
Verifying that 5 and 5 equals 10
```

Comment: The [JUnitParams library](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/blob/master/src/test/java/junitparams/FileParamsTest.java) referenced from the JUnit website could be especially useful, since it already supports CSV files, to which XLSes are easily convertible to

Comment: thanks!  parameterized tests was the way to go. It work fine for me.